# [^Z]+ what does this mean in Regex (Python)?

Tags: python, regex

`[^Z]+slogan: "([^"]*)` What does this mean in Regex (Python)? It returns "Life is a trip"

In this portion code:

```
< 0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",barca Ztry{if (!window.Cloud) {var Cloud=[{verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{cloud:"/cbcex-cmi/nexp/dok7v=02fcfa4f56, slogan: "Life is too short"
name="description" content="scream your longs out now." 
name="description slogan: "Life is a trip" selling real estate />
```

[screenshot of matching http://imageshack.com/a/img607/3699/5l2n.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img607/3699/5l2n.png)

I'm trying to understand why isn't it returning "Life is too short", the 1st instance of slogan: `" .....???`?

What it returns is in GREEN, NOT YELLOW. Note there are 2 instances of slogan: " in the code, why doesn't it choose the 1st one and return "Life is too short"? Still confused.

Thank You!

Comment: Read about greedy matching.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: normally the regex returns the max length coincidence, in this case it doesn't return " ... life is too short" because it can return something longer

First: [^Z]+ = "Every character except Z, at least once (1 times or more)"

Then it finds =  slogan: '

and end with [^'] = "Every character except ' 0 times or more"

The result it's something like:
(some characters but not Z) slogan:" (other characters or none, but not ")

That's why it start after the Z, and finishes before the " (after slogan: " )

Comment: Thanks tutrle! but I'm not sure I follow your logic! based on your explanation it should return everything between after Z and before the " after slogan, BUT it only returns "life is a trip"!!! Question1. Does it use an "AND GATE" as it steps through the expression? Question2. wrt to your comment about returning the "max length coincidence" I never heard that one b4!! but what if the length of the strings after 2nd slogan was equal to that of 1st, which one gets returned? Question3: Is it true that regex has to be written so that there is only a UNIQUE match? Thanks again for the education.